# Variable sized type allocation

Tags: c++, memory-management

I have a type that receives serial data over a pipe:

```
struct Packet : Base { // Base is POD, too
  int foo;
  char data[];
};
```

In the context, where I instantiate `Packet`, I already know how large this particular packet will be, so I write:

```
size_t const size = sizeof(Packet) + dataLength;
std::auto_ptr<Base> p(new((void*)(new char[size])) Packet());
// note that it will be deleted via 'delete'
```

Is this a sensible way of doing this, or is there a more idiomatic way?

Comment: In my opinion this approach makes a lot more sense in C than it does in C++.  I've seen it more often in projects which choose to do C rather than C++.  (In fact AFAIK this is standardized in C99 but not C++.)  C++ has higher level data structures like `vector` and also inheritance, both of which can be applied to this and similar problems.

Comment: I think we need to move this question to SO and get more eyes on it. But it is not how I would do it.

Comment: @LokiAstari, Stack Overflow isn't going to like how subjective this one is.

Comment: To clarify, it must be done like this, because `Packet` must be  POD.

Comment: @LokiAstari How do you feel this is off topic for here?

Comment: @MichaelK: It is non working code that needs a broader set of eyes to fix. But after Winston comment above. I wrote a slight [variation of the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240212/what-is-the-difference-between-new-delete-and-malloc-free/240308#240308) on SO to get better feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main thing I see wrong is that you are not accounting for `sizeof(foo)`.

The other problem is that auto_ptr<> will not de-allocate the memory correctly. It  calls `delete X`, but this is not legal as you did not allocate the memory with `new`. You need a custom destroy function (as you can provide to std::unique_ptr) that does the following:

Note: Original Question was:

```
std::auto_ptr<Base> p(malloc(size)) Packet());
```

Leading to my original answer:

```
// Assuming Packet*   packet = // stufff

packet->~Packet();   // Need to call destructor
free(packet);        // then free the memory allocated with malloc
```

Why not do this?

```
size_t const size = ...;
std::auto_ptr<Base> p = new Packet(size);
```

Then change packet too:

```
struct Packet : Base
{
  int foo;
  std::vector<char> data;
  Packet(size_t size): foo(0), data(size) {}
};
```

Edit:

Based on the comments and the updated question:

I posted the question here (to get more eyes on it): https://stackoverflow.com/q/9714359/14065

Which brought up two points:

- You still can use std::auto_ptr<>

  - The memory allocated with `new char[size]` must be freed by `delete []`
    This is not supported by std::auto_ptr<> though you may be able to use std::unique_ptr
- Secondly the implementation is allowed to put a marker after the end of the object

  - A few other points need to be considered so please read the linked questiom.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. The Packet has to be POD because it's sent over a `pipe` to another process. Regarding `foo`, `size` is supposed to include all members of `Packet` not just `data`, so that's covered. Now, what I don't quite get is, why it is a problem do `delete` the `Packet`. Wont this exactly call the dtor and the `free` the memory?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240212/what-is-the-difference-between-new-delete-and-malloc-free/240308#240308 for the why delete will not work.

Comment: See update. It looks spooky, but should be legal and do the right thing, right?

Comment: @bitmask: AFAIK, doing this is only legal in C as it has special rules for a `T[]` (incomplete array type) at the end of a struct. C++ has no such special handling and thus this is not allowed.